# Combining object key value pairs based on object key

Tags: arrays, sorting, mergesort

I have an array of key value pairs. A date and a quantity, but many have the same date, and I need to combine the quantities for each specific date. I've tried a million different for loops and pushing to an array in every way I can think of using vanilla JS, then moved to lodash and still no avail. This is what I currently have.

```
`data = [
[February 3rd 2020: 1]
[February 4th 2020: 1]
[February 3rd 2020: 3]
[February 5th 2020: 2]
]`
```

I can get an array of unique dates, and an array of unique values, but I'm stuck when it comes to getting the values combined in any form so that the quantities for each date can be manipulated into simple arithmetic... sum, average...

Appreciate it.

Comment: What is the actual code since that is not valid

Comment: It's honestly such a jumbled mess I don't know where to start. I'm getting data in this with these fields.    log: {id, date_submitted, quantity, submitted_by, etc. } The only fields that really matter are the date_submitted and the quantity, but there are several submitted per day, and for my life I can't figure out how to create arrays for every individual date containing the quantities, especially since this is continuous and the dates will change.

Comment: This is what a console.log of one of the items returns: `sale_date: "February 6th 2020, 1:45:37 pm"
_id: "5e3c6cfe12c0871e98094687"
item_id: "5e3b8d3cc0b49d1f8e3530dc"
Sale_id: "17e08ced-f1ed-4d75-acc9-b23732b21ecc"
description: "Need to add function on receiving modal"
quantity: 5
amount: 0
date: "2020-02-06T19:46:06.572Z"`